# Sort Russian index

Tags: imakeidx, makeindex, russian

I need to sort russian words in list of index in beamer. How I can do this ? I use Texstudio ,texlive .

```
  \documentclass[mathserif,12pt,aspectratio=169]{beamer}


    \usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[russian]{babel}
    \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[scaled=0.95]{PTSans}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    %\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
    \usepackage{epstopdf}
    \usepackage{algorithm}
    \usepackage{algorithmic}
    \usepackage{latexsym,amssymb,amsthm}




    \usepackage{multicol}


    \newenvironment{theindex}{}{}
    \usepackage{imakeidx}
    \renewenvironment{theindex}{%
        \let\item\par   % definitions for subitem etc
        \let\subitem\par
        \let\subsubitem\par
    }
    \makeatletter
    \def\@idxitem{\par}

    \def\imki@firstpagestyle{empty}
    \makeatother
    \newcommand\indexspace{}
    \makeindex

    \begin{document} 
    \begin{frame}
    \index{Алгоритм}
    \end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    \index{Банан}
    \end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    \index{Велосипед}
    \end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    \index{Гамма}
    \end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    \index{Дом}
    \end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    \index{Жизнь}
    \end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    \index{Здание}
    \end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    \index{Игра}
    \end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    \index{Еда}
    \end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    \index{Цена}
    \end{frame}
    \begin{frame}
    \index{Стоимость}
    \end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    \index{Яблоко}
    \end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    \index{Устье}
    \end{frame}
    \printindex
    \end{document}
```

Comment: I knew we'd arrive a this point. MakeIndex can't do it. You need Xindy.

Comment: But, please, if you want people to do experiments to make suggestions, the example should contain Russian words. And, above all: what's the purpose of an index in a beamer presentation?

Comment: @egreg , You mean write \usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx} ,but it didn`t help, may be I do something wrong. Okey I edited the example . I need index in beamer for lectures ( very big presentation for 4-5 lectures) and list of indexes will be usefull for students

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two sorts of problems:

1. MakeIndex does not cope with alphabets other than Latin
2. Index entries get expanded

You need to use Xindy as the index manager and tell it that you're using the Russian language.

If you want the automatic management of the index, `pdflatex` has to be run with the `-shell-escape` option enabled.

```latex
\documentclass[mathserif,12pt,aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scaled=0.95]{PTSans}

\newenvironment{theindex}{}{}
\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}
\renewenvironment{theindex}{%
  \let\item\par   % definitions for subitem etc
  \let\subitem\par
  \let\subsubitem\par
}
\makeatletter
\def\@idxitem{\par}
\def\imki@firstpagestyle{empty}
\makeatother
\newcommand\indexspace{}

\makeindex[options=-L russian -C utf8]

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\originalindex\index
  \renewcommand{\index}[1]{\originalindex{\detokenize{#1}}}%
}

\begin{document} 
\begin{frame}
\index{Алгоритм}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\index{Банан}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\index{Велосипед}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\index{Гамма}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\index{Дом}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\index{Жизнь}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\index{Здание}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\index{Игра}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\index{Еда}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\index{Цена}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\index{Стоимость}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\index{Яблоко}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\index{Устье}
\end{frame}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but how I can do it at the end of document ?

Comment: @re1nex What do you mean?

Comment: I have some problem \makeindex doesn`t undestand parameters .It underlines it and nothing change

Comment: How I can turn on option ?

Comment: Thank you very much !! at Miktex it works)

Comment: SplitIndex works with unicode under xelatex in the `article` document class.

Comment: Wanted to say: Slightly simpler coding with SplitIndex: SplitIndex produces an index under xelatex in the `article` document class straight out of the box, but with `beamer` it needs the index environment defined, plus a `\newcommand\hyperpage{}`, plus a suitable font on a per-frame basis. It looks like the perl script behind SplitIndex understands unicode, or perhaps xindy might be being called in the background.

Comment: @egreg , Can you look this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/487919/name-of-printidnex-and-alignment-indexes please ?