# Name of printindex and alignment indexes

Tags: beamer, indexing, imakeidx, makeindex

I have List of indexes in beamer , but it 
no indent before the name of slide. When I write \hspace it do very big indent .

```
    \usepackage{multicol}
\newenvironment{theindex}{}{}
\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}

\renewenvironment{theindex}{%

    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
    {{{\hspace{+4pt}\begin{center}\color{blue}\large{\indexname}\end{center}}}}
    \let\item\par   % definitions for subitem etc
    \def\subitem{\par\nobreak\hspace*{1em}\ignorespaces}%
    \def\subsubitem{\par\nobreak\hspace*{2em}\ignorespaces}%
    \def\indexspace{}%
    \begin{multicols}{2}
    }{\end{multicols}   }
\makeindex[options=-L russian -C utf8]
```

And I need to do right carry of subitems .Like this

[image]

but i have this

[image]

please help.

Example :

```
\documentclass[mathserif,12pt,aspectratio=169]{beamer}


\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scaled=0.95]{PTSans}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{latexsym,amssymb,amsthm}




\usepackage{multicol}
    \newenvironment{theindex}{}{}
    \usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}

    \renewenvironment{theindex}{%

        \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
        {{{\hspace{+4pt}\begin{center}\color{blue}\large{\indexname}\end{center}}}}
        \let\item\par   % definitions for subitem etc
        \def\subitem{\par\nobreak\hspace*{1em}\ignorespaces}%
        \def\subsubitem{\par\nobreak\hspace*{2em}\ignorespaces}%
        \def\indexspace{}%
        \begin{multicols}{2}
        }{\end{multicols}   }
    \makeindex[options=-L russian -C utf8]

\begin{document} 
\begin{frame}
\index{apple}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\index{Algorithm}
\end{frame}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[mathserif,12pt,aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage[scaled=0.95]{PTSans}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{latexsym,amssymb,amsthm}

\newenvironment{theindex}{}{}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}

\renewenvironment{theindex}
{\vspace*{-15pt}\begin{center}\Large Index\end{center}%
 \def\item{\par\hangindent 10pt\parindent0pt}%
  \begin{multicols}{2}
}{\end{multicols}}
\newcommand\subitem{\par\hangindent10pt\parindent10pt}
\newcommand\subsubitem{\par\hangindent20pt\parindent20pt}
\def\indexspace{}%

\makeindex[options=-L russian -C utf8]

\begin{document} 
\begin{frame}
\index{apple}\index{ABC}\index{ABC!abc!123}
foo\index{Algorithm}
\index{apple!Algorithm!This text as subsubitem which is very very long}
\index{apple!Algorithm as subitem}

\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\index{apple!Algorithm as subitem which is very very very extraordinary long}
foo
\index{short}\index{long}\index{very!long!As subsubitem this is a very very long subindex entry of long}
bar
\end{frame}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Looking good, I tried multiple columns towards another question and found the beamer frames limiting (In my attempt different index would not wrap column well and bound to one page) I am not asking you to ensure your code can exceed those limits, but it would be useful to know if you encountred any limitations at column, frame or page boundaries.

Comment: look for beamers `allowframebreaks`. I do not know if it works for an index.

Comment: There are some inherent odd behaviours at column end but overall wraps to next frame/page overcoming many of the poor behaviours I encountered. Since working in an uncommon fashion those oddities are generally to be expected and may need specific real world case by case manipulation. Anyway well done, bounty is time restricted so cant award just now +1

Comment: Sure, it is `beamer` and not a simple document class. I suppose that you have to insert manual frame breaks